# How can I let the user input repeat my code in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

Here is my code so far. (this is part of it, it's very long) I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I have tried searching for other answers on this website and tried something similar but still don't get it. I am not really understanding how this while loop should work since my code is, as I said, very long. I just can't figure it out and it's confusing me a lot. Please help?

```
 do{
  String retake;

  System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Type in Y for yes or N for no ");

  retake = kbd.nextLine();
  } while ( yes.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
 }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking user's choice in retake variable so check while condition with retake. Like below:

```
    // declare retake variable in outer scope
    string retake;
    do{

       //String retake;

    /**
        Put your code logic here!
     */


    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Type in Y for yes or N for no ");

    retake = kbd.nextLine();
  } while ( retake.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally worked. You have no idea how much this helped me. My project is due in a week and this really saved me!